# Sound playing in netbeans but not jar

Tags: java, netbeans, nullpointerexception

This snippet of code is supposed to play a short beep after the method is executed. Which it is doing inside netbeans. But when I use netbeans to build an executable Jar file it gives me a java.Lang.NullPointerException. Any ideas?

```
public void playSound() {

      try {
          AudioStream as = new AudioStream(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources\\beep-2.wav"));
          AudioPlayer.player.start(as); 
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

Comment: whenever problem has been shorted out accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a forward slash; backslash is Windows-specific and will only work when you're using an exploded layout.

Answer (score 1):

change the code into the following it will surely work..

```
 public void playSound() {

    try {

         AudioStream as = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(this.getClass().getResource("resources\\beep-2.wav"));
         Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
         clip.open(as);
         clip.start( );
       }
    catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not able to find your audio file. Make a resources folder in the directory where you jar is kept and keep the audio file in that folder.

Alternatively you can give an exact path in your program. e.g. C:\resources\beep-2.wav